# Adding new variable to dataframe equally

Tags: r, variables, sampling

using RStudio, I have this :

```
GROUP NUM
A     45
A     78
A     79  
B     45
B     47
B     99
C     28
C     78
C     54
```

I want to add a new variable, named AGENT, which is:

```
AGENT=c("John", "Maria", "Pamela")
```

But the problem is that, I want each of my Agent to be equally spreaded amongsts the initial dataframe according to the ID. Basically, I want this:

```
GROUP NUM AGENT
A     45  John
A     78  Maria
A     79  Pamela
B     45  John 
B     47  Maria
B     99  Pamela
C     28  John
C     78  Maria
C     54  Pamela
```

My example here is basic because I have as many groups as I have agents. However in my case, I might have 70 of each letter (70 A, 70 B and 70 C) and still only 3 agents. I still want them to be spread as equally as possible....

For example, if I had 6 A, I would have :

```
GROUP NUM AGENT
A     45  John
A     78  Maria
A     79  Pamela
A     48  John
A     97  Maria
A     59  Pamela
...
```

And if I had 7, then 7th would be assigned randomly, or just the next on the list.

Any ideas? I've been torturing myself over this. Thanks in advance! :P

Answer (score 3):

If "*or just the next on the list.*" is appropriate for any overflow when the group is larger, you can take advantage of vector recycling and just do it in one assignment:

```
dat$newvar <- with(dat, ave(1:nrow(dat), GROUP, FUN=function(x) AGENT) )
dat
#  GROUP NUM newvar
#1     A  45   John
#2     A  78  Maria
#3     A  79 Pamela
#4     B  45   John
#5     B  47  Maria
#6     B  99 Pamela
#7     C  28   John
#8     C  78  Maria
#9     C  54 Pamela
```

Just ignore any warnings you might get when the groups are not neatly matched to the size of `AGENT`

`data.table` could be used too, in a similar fashion:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dat[, newvar2 := AGENT, by=GROUP]
```

Comment: I found this answer for a similar problem. It works for me as well, but the vector I'd like to add contains dates. When I add it this way, the dates are transformed into numeric variables. Simply wrapping with(...) in as.Date() doesn't work. It throws the error: 'origin' must be supplied.

Any ideas perhaps?

Comment: @Tingolfin - you can specify the default `origin=` manually `as.Date(ave(...), origin="1970-01-01")`, or use a `Date` object in the initial `ave` call like `ave(rep(AGENT[1],nrow(dat)), dat$GROUP, FUN=function(x) AGENT)`

Answer (score 0):

I come up with a bit complicated way to do it using the index. There might be a much easier way. Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
AGENT <- c("John", "Maria", "Paul") 

fun <- function(x){
 x %>% mutate(agent=AGENT[((1:nrow(.) - 1) %% 3) + 1])
}

df %>% 
  split(.$GROUP) %>%
  lapply(fun) %>%
  bind_rows()

  GROUP NUM agent
1     A  45  John
2     A  78 Maria
3     A  79  Paul
4     B  45  John
5     B  47 Maria
6     B  99  Paul
7     C  28  John
8     C  78 Maria
9     C  54  Paul
```

If there isn't too many data or the length of `GROUP` is not the multiple of `AGENT`, it will create the variable follow the order of `AGENT`.

```
df1 

GROUP NUM
1     A  45
2     A  78
3     B  45
4     C  28

df1 %>% 
  split(.$GROUP) %>%
  lapply(fun) %>%
  bind_rows()

  GROUP NUM agent
1     A  45  John
2     A  78 Maria
3     B  45  John
4     C  28  John
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
# Data
df <- data.frame("GROUP" = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"),
             "NUM" = c(45,78,79,45,47,99,28,78,54))
AGENT=c("John", "Maria", "Pamela")

# Assign agents
df$agent <- NA
groups <- levels(factor(df$GROUP))

lapply(groups, function(x)
       {
        df[df$GROUP == x, "agent"] <<- 
        c(rep(AGENT, as.integer(length(df[df$GROUP == x, "NUM"]) / 3)),
          AGENT[0:(length(df[df$GROUP == x, "NUM"]) %% 3)])
       })
```

If there are more than 3 agents, replace the 3 in the script by length(AGENT)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect the use of `<<-` might set off alarms for some folk.